# Button in ActionBar setting visibility?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbaractivity

I have 3 `Fragments`, and in `Fragment3` I want display an icon in my `ActionBar`, this is works fine but when I do back to other fragments like Fragment1 and Fragment2 the icon stay `visible(true)`
I tried add `item.setVisible(false)` in `onPause` of Fragment, but doesn't works and the icon stay shown in others `Fragments`

How can I solve it ?

**XML**

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_chat"
    android:icon="@drawable/batalha_icon_chat"
    android:title="Chat"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:visible="true"
    />
```

**Fragment**

```
public class Fragment3 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Menu mMenu;

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.battle_chat, menu);
    mMenu = menu;
    MenuItem mi = mMenu.findItem(R.id.action_chat);
    if(this.isVisible()){
        Log.i("VISIBLE->", "true");
        mi.setVisible(true);
    }else{
        Log.i("VISIBLE->", "false");
        mi.setVisible(false);
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}


@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_chat:
                Fragment frag = new HelloBubblesActivity();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fl, frag,"HelloBubblesActivity");     
                ft.commit();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


 @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    //API 9
    getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

Comment: Is onPause actually beign invoked? (I don't think so) Place a Log or toast above "...setvisible" to trace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call: `invalidateOptionsMenu();`
This will call `onCreateOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: I did change my post `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPause` , but doesn't works. Any idea ?

Comment: Set the menu entry always as invisible, when you enter the fragment, set it as visible. This should work.

Comment: to invalidate I need do it inside ActionBarActivity or in my Fragment3 ?

Comment: You can do it in the Fragment, because you are calling getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

But you also need to have some code in your activty to hide the menu, because the onPause supportInvalidateOptionsMenu call will call the method onPrepareOptionsMenu in your activity.